# Generic approach for styling n-children depending on the actual number n

Tags: html, css

With CSS3 it's totally possible to create rules like:

```
.myClass {}

myClass:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}

myClass:first-child:nth-last-child(5) {
    width: 20%;
}
```

So depending on the number of *possible* children I'd need to specify *additional* rules, which is somewhat awesome that even possible, but still very cumbersome.

So I'm wondering if there is some fancy *generic* way of doing this, maybe involving `css counters` and `calc()` or the like?

To **clarify**: I'm just curious if there is a **css-only** solution available. I know I can achieve the same thing with the help of pre-processors or even (java)script(s).

To **further clarify**: Instead of having to define rules for every possible number of children I want to create exactly **one** (to rule them all ;)) that, depending on the actual number of children defines the width accordingly.

So, say: `4 children -> calc(100%/4)`, `n children -> calc(100%/n)`

Comment: You should try LESS or SASS. You can create functions and mixins that will server your purpose.
Check them out: http://lesscss.org/# or http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Thank you, but I am not asking for another solution and I'm aware of less, sass and other pre-processors :)

Comment: It's not clear what you are actually asking. Are you trying something like [**Quantity Queries**](http://quantityqueries.com/)

Comment: There is actually no way of knowing this since CSS cannot count elements as a group, just upwards. A preprocessor makes this easier, but the output is still very much based on the numbers you put in. So no, dynamically this is impossible.

Comment: CSS is not conditional or a programming language so although I'm still not sure what you are asking I suspect the answer is "No".

Comment: @Paulie_D: It is not, true, but it has features like calc() and css-counters etc. So I wanted to check if something, that I didn't know of has been added to the specs in the last couple of years... I mean, hell, you can make much more today than 10 years ago, when I really was into HTML and CSS :)

Comment: Those aren't conditional or programming operations.

Comment: @Paulie_D: No, they are not, but I could've missed something, hence I asked. (Although I used google before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I'm understanding you correctly, what you really want is for a number of elements to occupy an equal width evenly divided on the same row? If so, flexbox might be what you are actually looking for. Setting a container to `display: flex;` and then letting the children (flex items in this context) have `flex: 0 1 auto;` (i.e. don't grow above your content, shrink as needed etc.)

I set up a CodePen to show a very basic example: http://codepen.io/frippz/pen/bVReYB

Comment: Thank you, but no, I just wanted to ask if I've missed something in terms of CSS3-selectors.

Comment: Ah, well then I can at least provide you with this article by Heydon Pickering. Maybe that might be at least something in the ballpark. http://www.heydonworks.com/article/tetris-the-power-of-css